# laravel remove id if user not login

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

In my site a user can add new order if isn't logged in
after login update order by user id

Now some users don't login and leave page
I ask if any way to check if user login or leave page
if leave page or not login I will delete order

```
if(Input::get('id_order')){
  DB::table('orders')->where('id', Input::get('id_order'))->update(['id_user' => Auth::user()->id]);
  return Redirect::to('ViewOrder/'.Input::get('id_order').'');
}else{    
  return Redirect::to('/')->with('success',Lang::get('main.login_success'));
}
```

Comment: You can alternatively save the order in the local storage and with for a user to login. Then you can assign that order to the user that is logged in

Answer (score 1):

Save it in user session ( session does not mean logged in)
And when user login, get all orders user has in his session and update the order table id to user log in

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session

Answer (score 0):

First check if user is logged in with

```
if (Auth::check()) {
// The user is logged in...
}
```

Put the update statement in if clause.

```
if (Auth::check()) {
 DB::table('orders')->where('id', Input::get('id_order'))->update(['id_user' => Auth::user()->id]);
 }
```

otherwise delete the order by order id.

```
DB::table('orders')->delete(['id' => Input::get('id_order')]);
```